# Injecting Configuration Properties is not working in my test

Tags: spring-boot

I'm stuck!  If I skip tests and deploy to tomcat auto wiring the configuration properties file works.  In my test, it fails!  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my setup:

Spring Boot v 1.2.5.RELEASE
Application.yml

```
git:
  localRepo: './powershell-status-scripts/'
  remoteRepo: 'https://github.com/...'
```

RepositoryProperties this class has getters and setters for the properties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application.yml", prefix = "git", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class RepositoryProperties {

    private String localRepo;

    private String remoteRepo;

    public RepositoryProperties() {

    }

    public String getLocalRepo() {
        return localRepo;
    }

    public void setLocalRepo(String localRepo) {
        this.localRepo = localRepo;
    }

    public String getRemoteRepo() {
        return remoteRepo;
    }

    public void setRemoteRepo(String remoteRepo) {
        this.remoteRepo = remoteRepo;
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sendash.admin")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sendash.admin.dao.jpa") 
@EnableSwagger 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(applicationClass);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

}
```

GitService - Autowiring the properties works on tomcat!

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class GitService {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryProperties repositoryProperties;

    public void updateLocalRepository() {
      ...
    }
```

GitServiceTest this class fails on init because of a NPE.  Properties is null.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Profile("test")
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
public class GitServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private static GitService manager;

    @Autowired
    private static RepositoryProperties properties;

    private static final String localRepoLocation = properties.getLocalRepo();
```

I do realize after pasting this that @EnableConfigurationProperties is on both the Application.java and the GitService.java class.  Stopping the duplication does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did change my ContextConfiguration as suggested, but my main problem was trying to autowire a static field.  It was static for @BeforeClass test setup logic so I needed to move things around a bit, but I got it working.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Spring Boot in your tests, you should configure the tests accordingly. To do that, remove the ContextConfiguration and add the following:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

This should enable injecting the configuration properties.